# Is there a way to enable path completion in my clojure script?

Tags: clojure

I am writing a script in Clojure that will ask user to input a file-path where it will check if the path exists then perform some action on it. It works but then I am wondering is there a way to enable path completion to clojure's read-line so that the user can tab to complete the file-path during input ?

Answer (score 1):

read-line is a very generic function that is not intended specifically for reading file paths. So I believe that if you'd like path completions, you'd have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box metod, but as Shlomi wrote, you can implement it yourself.
Take a look at [PrefixFileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/PrefixFileFilter.html) from apache-commons and do something like:

```
File dir = new File("/");
String[] files = dir.list(new PrefixFileFilter("o"));
```

Which will return list of files in '/' starting with 'o'.